# Array Push Adds Data Only Once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't add more than one data to array. I couldn't solve this problem running on basic javascript events.

```
$(".add-cart").on("click", function () {
        let products = []
        let name, price

        name = "product 1"
        price = "200"

        products.push({
            name: name,
            price: price
        })
        // i will click so many times and result is only one length array
        // products
        // [{name: 'product 1', price: 200}]
    });
```

Comment: You are redeclaring the array on every click, so it will only ever have one object in it. You need to declare your array outside of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define that array outside of your event. So every time you click it uses the same reference to add your data.

```js
let products = []
$(".add-cart").on("click", function () {
        let name, price

        name = "product 1"
        price = "200"

        products.push({
            name: name,
            price: price
        })
        // i will click so many times and result is only one length array
        // products
        // [{name: 'product 1', price: 200}]
    });
```